# Ajustar Gama de Imagem usando Python

Tags: python, opencv, processamento-de-imagens

Sou iniciante em python, mas tenho experiência com outras linguagens de programação. Preciso fazer um trabalho da faculdade, mas não sei como prosseguir. Gostaria de saber como ajustar o gama de uma imagem usando python, fiz o download de algumas bibliotecas de processamento de imagens (como o opencv). Gostaria de saber se existe alguma função que faça isso no python ou caso não exista, poderiam me informar qual seria o processo pra fazer esse ajuste? Porque conhecendo o processo eu posso criar o algoritmo na "mão".

OBS: se possível, evitem respostas apenas baseadas em links externos, isto é, não deixem como resposta apenas o link para uma página externa.

OBS2: não tenho nada "pronto", apenas estou lendo a imagem utilizando o opencv.

```
import cv2
imagem = cv2.imread("../Imagens/im01.jpg");
```

Comment: Por curiosidade, por quê não aceitar links que não sejam do SO? E se for necessário citar a documentação oficial da ferramenta?

Comment: opa @AndersonCarlosWoss, links para referência da documentação são muito bem vindos. O que quis dizer com evitar links externos é que alguns usuários colocam como resposta apenas o link para algum site externo e se esse site futuramente venha a cair, alguém que venha a ter o mesmo problema que eu não conseguirá obter a solução. Já passei por isso várias vezes, acho uma solução que leva para um link externo, mas a página não existe mais. Entendeu o que quis dizer?

Comment: Agora sim, então ficaria mais explícito na pergunta colocar "evitem resposta apenas baseadas em links", mas isso também é desnecessário, pois isso é uma das filosofias internas da comunidade e se houver alguma resposta assim ela será notificada e possivelmente removida.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss entendi, vou editar a pergunta com sua sugestão.

Comment: Olá. Vc diz que se trata de um trabalho de faculdade, então eu entendo que faz parte do seu aprendizado aprender a fazer o programa. A sua pergunta é válida, mas vc essencialmente diz: "alguém tem aí o código pronto?". Bom, na documentação você acha o código pronto, já chegou a olhar ela? E uma simples busca por "gamma correction opencv" na Internet te retorna muito material bacana, como por exemplo: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/05/opencv-gamma-correction/ Não é má vontade minha em responder, mas eu acho que vai te ajudar mais se você tentar algo antes. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira entendi Luiz, acho que acabei me expressando mal, me desculpe por isso. A intenção da minha pergunta foi saber se já existia alguma função no python que já fazia isso e caso não existisse, saber quais seriam os procedimentos para fazer isso (no caso, os passos teóricos), pois sou totalmente leigo nesse assunto de processamento de imagens. Sabendo do processo, eu mesmo criaria o algoritmo na mão sem problemas. Mas obrigado por responder, olharei o link que você passou e caso eu consiga resolver o problema, vou deixar uma resposta para futuros usuários.

Comment: Sem problemas. :) Aliás, lembre-se que vc é muito bem vindo a postar sempre aqui! Eu só acho que , perguntas mais interessantes (que, aliás, geram mais reputação) são aquelas com problemas mais bem descritos/caracterizados. Sobre entender o processo, uma boa fonte de leitura é essa: http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/gamma-correction.htm

Answer (score 2):

O seguinte código resolve para você (ref: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/05/opencv-gamma-correction/):

```
def adjust_gamma(image, gamma=1.0):
    # build a lookup table mapping the pixel values [0, 255] to
    # their adjusted gamma values
    invGamma = 1.0 / gamma
    table = np.array([((i / 255.0) ** invGamma) * 255
        for i in np.arange(0, 256)]).astype("uint8")

    # apply gamma correction using the lookup table
    return cv2.LUT(image, table)
```

Vamos entender como funciona.
O ajuste de gama funciona da seguinte forma:
O = I ^ (1 / G)

ou seja, a saída é a imagem, normalizada de um valor entre 0 e 1, elevada a 1/gama. É isso que a função `adjust_gamma` faz.

Você poderia simplesmente dividir o valor de cada pixel da imagem por 255 e depois elevar ao invGamma, mas aí estaria fazendo a mesma conta milhares de vezes, o que é ineficiente. Lembre-se que uma imagem pequena pode conter dezenas ou centenas de milhares de pixels.

Portanto, o que se faz é uma tabela que relaciona todos os valores possíveis de um pixel [0_255] com seu valor ajustado com a correção gama.

Depois, basta fazer um "lookup table" muito eficiente implementado pela opencv: `cv2.LUT`.