# Como eliminar componentes de uma imagem usando python?

Tags: python, opencv, processamento-de-imagens

Sou iniciante em python e gostaria de saber como eliminar componentes (vermelho, azul ou verde) de uma imagem usando python, fiz o download de algumas bibliotecas de processamento de imagens (como o opencv). Gostaria de saber se existe alguma função que faça isso no python ou caso não exista, poderiam me informar qual seria o processo pra fazer isso? Conhecendo o processo eu posso criar o algoritmo na "mão". 

OBS: se possível, evitem respostas apenas baseadas em links externos, isto é, não deixem como resposta apenas o link para uma página externa.

OBS2: não tenho nada "pronto", apenas estou lendo a imagem utilizando o opencv.

```
import cv2
imagem = cv2.imread("../Imagens/im01.jpg");
```

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, não é a mesma pergunta, é uma pergunta nova. Estava com 2 dúvidas sobre manipulação de imagens, como colocar as 2 numa pergunta só poderia causar problemas, postei cada uma separada da outra

Comment: Erro meu. Desculpa.

Comment: Colega, o que vc quer dizer com "eliminar"? Seria remover o canal de uma certa cor, mantendo apenas os outros canais? Supondo que sim, dá uma olhada neste link (ou procure por "python opencv RGB split" no Google): http://knowpapa.com/opencv-rgb-split/ Como eu [comentei na sua outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/260091/ajustar-gama-de-imagem-usando-python#comment533369_260091), não é que o assunto não seja válido, mas eu acho que você deveria tentar algo antes porque vai te ajudar no seu aprendizado. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira olá novamente Luiz. Cara, o pior que eu pesquisei antes sobre o assunto, mas o meu mal é que na maioria das vezes eu não sei como elaborar a pesquisa. Coloquei inicialmente "eliminate components of image using python", mas isso não me retornou bons resultados. Olharei seu link e usarei a sua sugestão de pesquisa. Novamente, obrigado por responder e me ajudar.

Comment: Opa, por nada. É, realmente essa é a dificuldade. :) Tome cuidado especialmente com a palavra "componente", porque no processamento de imagens ela quase sempre quer dizer algo como "uma parte característica de um elemento de interesse que vc busca na imagem", como as bordas curvas de uma moeda numa foto de moedas, saca?

Comment: E se vc está estudando processamento de imagens, sugiro pegar uma fonte boa de estudo (um livro como o ["*Image Processing and Acquisition using Python*"](https://www.amazon.com/Processing-Acquisition-Mathematical-Computational-Sciences/dp/1466583754)) pra ao menos entender os termos básicos e tals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode 'zerar' os canais de cores de forma independente da seguinte maneira:

```
# Removendo canal AZUL
img[:,:,0] = 0  

# Removendo canal VERDE
img[:,:,1] = 0  

# Removendo canal VERMELHO
img[:,:,2] = 0
```

Segue um exemplo de código capaz de remover canais específicos de uma dada imagem:

```
import cv2
import copy

# Abre image original
img = cv2.imread("original.png")

# Remove canal AZUL
img_no_blue = copy.copy(img)
img_no_blue[:,:,0] = 0

# Remove canal VERDE
img_no_green = copy.copy(img)
img_no_green[:,:,1] = 0

# Remove canal VERMELHO
img_no_red = copy.copy(img)
img_no_red[:,:,2] = 0

# Exibe as imagens
cv2.imshow('Imagem Original', img )
cv2.imshow('Azul Removido', img_no_blue )
cv2.imshow('Verde Removido', img_no_green )
cv2.imshow('Vermelho Removido', img_no_red )

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Imagem Original:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Canais Removidos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]